# Phonegap Application Start Issue

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I made a simple application with a few html pages all linked together, and had the android application build.

Now when i installed my application on an android device there is a black screen which is displayed after the splash screen and then the application starts.

I tried all that i could find online. but nothing worked out and fixed this issue.

Comment: have you tried hiding the splash screen when the device is ready ?

Comment: How long is the black screen?

Comment: about a couple of seconds

Answer (score 0):

Did you include cordova.js? The black screen is normal if you did not include cordova.js.

Comment: yepp i included phonegap.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I got a solution from the below link.

[Link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_dies_on_startup_connection_to_the_server_was_unsuccessful)

I solved it by renaming `index.html` to `main.html` for example, and create a new (dummy) `index.html` that only have to redirect to the `main.html` .

Hope it helps.